# Parameters OK at startup but problems when logging back

Tags: audio, keyboard, gnu-screen, logout

When I start the computer, everything works fine. But if I leave the computer, then when I log back to my session, I sometimes have 1 or 2 or 3 of those weird behaviors (not all, and not always, otherwise it wouldn't be confusing enough to come and ask you...):

- One of my 3 screens won't turn on ("no signal")
- the <kbd>e</kbd> key works as a dead key which cancels the next key. E.g. if I type `azerty`, then it will display `azty`
- The <kbd>^</kbd> dead key (maybe others too) won't work
- The sound output switches to USB output where there is no speaker

Once, the screen which turned off was the laptop screen, and from the main screen I checked the monitor settings and saw I could just click to turn back on the laptop screen. Which doesn't tell me why the system had turned it off. The other times, the screen which turned off was my main screen, and it was marked as active in the monitor settings.

3 days ago, I installed Debian 12 on my ASUS laptop. I have 2 external monitors connected via a Cablematters docking station: an old HP, and a more recent HP used as primary screen. I use a wireless keyboard set to French.
After the install, the only things I changed are:

- Compose on startup with the command `xmodmap -e "keysym Super_L = Multi_key"`
- installed Telegram, and make it start on startup
- Official Brother printer driver (but the problem started before that)
- Added a `~/.XCompose` starting with `include "%L"` and the rest being mostly the copy of the ISO8859-15 compose file, because without this file, the Compose key wasn't doing anything. Annoyingly, some of the defined shortcuts still don't work, but that's another problem, probably.
- Installed mono to run Subtitle Edit (works fine)

I think that's it. On day 1 I wanted to mount the Windows partition on startup, but I didn't find how (so I think I made no change there).

PS: I made some progress: When the main screen is off, by going into the monitor parameters, I can turn it back on back turning it off in the parameters. Very confusing, but at least like this I don't have to reboot.